# Why are True and 1 equivalent as dictionary keys?

Tags: python

I got a quite strange bug in my code... at some point I have to convert values to unicode strings, with the exception of some special values (None, True, False) that need special treatment.

The code looks something like this:

```
conversions = {
    None: 'null',
    True: 'true',
    False: 'false',
}

def translate(val):
    return conversions.get(val, unicode(val))
```

But when the value `1` is passed in, I got back `u'true'` while I was expecting `u'1'`. So I opened a console and played a little bit:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> d = {True: 'yeah', False: 'boooh'}

>>> d[1]
'yeah'
>>> d[0]
'boooh'

>>> 1 in d
True
>>> 0 in d
True

>>> True is 1
False
```

So, it turns out that `0` and `1` behave the same way as `True` and `False`. Why? it is confusing and leads to strange bugs like this...

Comment: `bool` is a subclass of `int`, for historical reasons. See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/ for the details.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot.

Comment: Also, because of how the sub-classing occurred, `True` and `1` have the same `hash()` value. Any items that have the same `hash()` value, will the same value from a `dict`.